# Is there any kind of proxy that would let people connect to me despite not being able to listen on ports?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

For example, one server which can listen on ports listens on a port for incoming connections and the backend proxy server. That backend server keeps connecting to the main proxy server and then the main server forwards application connections through it, where the backend sends it off again somewhere. Does this already exist/is it possible?

Comment: it's called [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Comment: @IporSircer Reverse proxies require the backend to be listening on a port though.

Comment: @JavaProphet This would not be possible with plain HTTP, you would have to have some kind of custom protocol between the proxy and the server in order to have the proxy act as the server and the HTTP server the client.

Comment: @heavyd I don't know what HTTP has to do anything, but is there any program that has done this before?